# PHPStorm less watcher - importing less files not sitting in a child directory

Tags: less, phpstorm, subdirectory

I want to trigger main.less compilation when i change sub.less. 'Track only root files' is on.

main.less (imports samelevel.less and sub.less)
samelevel.less
subdir/sub.less

When i change sonething in sub.less, main.less won't be compiled. When i change something in samelevel.less, main.less will be compiled.

How do i set this up?

Edit:
above was simplified and misleading, here my actual dir structure:

root/less/main.less
root/less/samelevel.less
root/subdir1/subdir2/sub.less

In main.less i do: @import "..\subdir1\subdir2\sub.less";

Edit2:
My goal is to automatically compile all less files via main.less > main.css. Currently i only achieve this when i change a less file inside root/less/.

Comment: Works fine for me (Windows 7 x64 here; LESS installed globally via npm; PhpStorm v6 an 7). Try naming included files with leading underscore (e.g. `_sub.less` and then reference them in main file via `@import "subdir/_sub";`).

Comment: Hmm, same system here. I see less background service activity in PHPStorm when i change sub.less, so less is running there. I'll try the underscore prefix.

Comment: No difference with underscore.

Comment: I see you have updated your directory structure .. and now included files are ABOVE the actual master file (not in subfolder of the same folder) -- quite likely this is what causing the issue. My suggestion in such case (if nothing else is working) -- provide FULL file name of the compiled .less instead of macro; if necessary -- use custom Scope and separate file watcher entry just for these files (in case you have other files that compile just fine).

Comment: Thank you LazyOne. What do you mean by 'provide FULL file name of compiled .less instead of macro'? Has this to do with 'Working directory = $FileDir$'?

Comment: No. This is default/standard content of "Arguments" field of File Watcher: `--no-color $FileName$`. As you can clearly see the `$FileName$` macro is used. If you replace it by FULL file name (full path) of the main file (e.g. `FULL/path/to/less/main.less`) it will always compile that file

Comment: If you wish (HIGHLY recommended): **1)** create brand new empty project; **2)** copy those files there (or just create very basic (few lines each) files that would represent similar file structure) **3)** Create and configure File Watcher **4)** Try compiling it. If it works properly -- must be project specific. If it does not -- upload such test project somewhere so I can grab it and test here on my computer. If it will not work here as well .. then it makes perfect sense to submit a bug report to JS Issue Tracker so it's gets fixed in v7.

Comment: I replaced $FileName$ with the absolute path to the main file to something like that C:/path/to/less/main.less, but no luck. I have to try a new project. Thanks for your patience :)